# Can I retrieve the row/column affected from a trigger in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there some sort of variable where the updated column/row/table is stored that I can access in the script for my trigger?

So lets say row of ID=3 of table 'myTable' has an update query performed on it. Is it possible for me to then perform an update query on table 'anotherTable' with ID=3?

Example Query:

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn=myValue
```

Example Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'update'
    AFTER UPDATE ON 'myTable'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE 'anotherTable'
            SET netInterest=(myValue * 0.09 /*pseudocode*/)
   END
```

Can this be done entirely in SQL?

Comment: yes of course, in trigger you have two magic table (new) and (old) that new one contains the new value and old contains the old value, the structure is as same as target(base) table, just query them and have your alternatives :D

Comment: Thank you.

I have one more question if you don't mind me asking. Is it possible to "tag" a table as a certain type? So if I were to make a trigger, I would want it to run only for tables that were supposed to be modeling a certain type of data, but there were also other tables modeling other types of data in the same database.

Comment: are you talking about using a trigger for more than one table? there is no any type need in fact, when a trigger search for a certain column, it doesn't matter about the name and base table, I have note that when you create a trigger you need to bind it ti a table at creation time, so for reuse it, you need to rewrite it, this is not a stand-alone object like in PostgreSQL, while you would transfer your code to a procedure and simply pass the magic tables to procedure, now you would use the procedure in many triggers

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'Trigger_name'
        AFTER UPDATE ON 'Table_Name'
        BEGIN
            UPDATE 'Another_Table_Name'
                SET Field_Name=10
       END
```